# Is there a way to use RoyalSlider within a fancyBox lightbox with filtered results?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, colorbox, jquery-isotope

I have been able to set up a photo gallery which can be filtered by categories. When a photo is clicked upon it launches a fancyBox lightbox which only cycles the filtered results.

What I would like to do is replace the slideshow within fancyBox with RoyalSlider since it is much more configurable and the transitions are far better. I have tried to set up the example with ColorBox hosting RoyalSlider but it does not seem to allow me to pass the filtered results like I have set up so far.

Here is a link to my jsfiddle with what I have working so far, try the filter buttons and you will see that the slideshow only cycles through the filtered results:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/lalush/G448F/embedded/result/**](http://jsfiddle.net/lalush/G448F/embedded/result/)

Here is the code I am using to filter the results. Is there any way to translate this for RoyalSlider to recognize the filtered results?

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').on("click", function () {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('#container').isotope({
            filter: selector
        }, function () {
            if (selector == "*") {
                $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
            } else {
                $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Will I be able to use RoyalSlider to show the filtered results? I am not that great at javascript but I have managed to configure this gallery so far from examples that I have found. I have been unable to find any examples of using fancyBox to host RoyalSlider even though is says it is able to work with ColorBox and fancyBox in the features for RoyalSlider.

Any help is greatly appreciated!